# Selenium: Execute third function after first two finished

Tags: python, selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver, pytest

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Firefox to run my code. I am using pytest so I can run the functions in parallel. I have three main functions: first and second function return something and third function uses the data from the pervious functions. **My problem is that I want to execute third function with the data returned from two functions once the first two functions have finished.**

The code itself is actually much more complex but to clarify I made a new code which demonstrates my problem. I have two functions, one is named "test1" and other is named "test2" - both of these run parallel and return information. I also have a third function named "test3" to process the data returned from test1 and test2 once they're both finished. In this example "comp" should just print out some text.

Here's the code:

```
import unittest
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

# pytest -s -v tests.py        <----- I use to execute this script
# py.test -s tests.py -d --tx 2*popen//python=python2.7    <------- I     use this to run the tests in parallel
# For some reason program doesnt print in parallel mode. Although "-s" fixes that in the normal execution of pytest.


class TestParallel(unittest.TestCase):


def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./dependencies/geckodriver')


def test1(self):
    browser = self.browser
    browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
    asd = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a").text # returns "Gmail"
    sleep(2)
    print asd
    return asd

def test2(self):
    browser = self.browser
    browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
    asd2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a").text # returns "Images"
    sleep(1)
    print asd2
    return asd2

def test3(self):
    print "word from test1 is " + TestParallel.test1(self) + " and word from test2 is " + TestParallel.test2(self)


def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Maybe someone has ideas/suggestions as to how I could resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: if it's not named test* it won't be executed by pytest

Comment: @Phoenix87 Thank you, I fixed the name. But my initial question still remains

Comment: You shouldn't make tests that are dependent on each other. Sounds like you should combine the tests in some way... but which way is hard to determine with so little information.

Comment: @JeffC using pytest is the only way I've found to run these two tests in parallel. Unfortunately it caused me a problem with processing the information in the third function. Could you please clarify what more information do you need to assist me?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Ok, here's another idea:

- Declare two empty global string variables before test1 and test2 are
  run.
- Have test1 and test2 write to those two variables
- Have test3
  wait with a while loop until both of the variables contain something
  or until a specific amount of time passes.

  ```
  class TestParallel(unittest.TestCase):

  string_a = ""
  string_b = ""

  def setUp(self):
      self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./dependencies/geckodriver')

  def test1(self):
      [..]
      string_a = "result_a"

  def test2(self):
      [..]
      string_b = "result_b"

  def test3(self):
      counter = 0;
      while ("" in string_a && "" in string_b):
          sleep(0.1)
          counter = counter + 1
          if counter > 200:
              break

  print "word from test1 is " + string_a + " and word from test2 is " + string_b
  ```

---

Hmm, perhaps:

```
def test3(self):
    counter = 0;
    while ("" in string_a && "" in string_b):
        sleep(0.1)
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter > 1000:
            break

    print "word from test1 is " + string_b + " and word from test2 is " + string_b
```

Comment: This code sadly has no use for me because it runs infidelity. Also, there must be another way to get the returned data from test1 and test2 because currently test3 runs test1 and test2 again.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: If you use global variables, e.g. `string_a` and `string_b`, and run this in parallel, the parallel runs will overwrite each other's data mixing the two runs which is bad(tm).

Comment: @JeffC Hmm but test1 only writes to string_a and test2 writes to string_b. How will they overwrite each other's data...? EDIT: Oh I see, each run starts with the two variables being blank. So only one of them will have a non-empty value at the end. I guess 010101010 could write the result of each test to a separate file, but that is also bad...

Comment: Imagine two runs happening at almost the same time... run1 writes "a" to string_a and "b" to string_b and then run2 writes "1" to string_a and "2" to string_b. Then run1 prints the contents of string_a and string_b as "1" and "2" instead of the "a" and "b" for it's own run.

Comment: Although this was not what I was looking for, I got an idea thanks to this code, that I will try very soon.

Answer (score 0):

`test1` and `test2` don't really look like tests... they look like they should be functions that return data from the page that are used in a test. I would do something more like

```
def get_thing1(self):
    return self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a").text # returns "Gmail"

def get_thing2(self):
    return self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a").text # returns "Images"

def test1(self):
    browser = self.browser
    browser.get('https://www.google.com/')

    print "word from test1 is " + get_thing1(self) + " and word from test2 is " + get_thing2(self)
```

These two methods, `get_thing1` and `get_thing2` assume that you are on the right page and all they do is return whatever you are looking for. Please change the names to something more descriptive... I wasn't sure what exactly they were returning so I made up some generic name.

Now you only have `test1` that runs and two methods that pull things from the page. You can run `test1` as many times as you want... in parallel, etc. ... in a loop or whatever you desire.

Extra notes:

1. You really don't want to use XPaths that are that many levels deep and/or that start at the HTML tag. They are very brittle (likely to break with any little change to the HTML).
2. You should take some time to read about the page object model. You should create a GoogleSearchResultsPage page object and have `get_thing1()` and `get_thing2()` be in that page object. You test would then progress from the GoogleSearchPage to the GoogleSearchResultsPage and would then call those two methods, etc. to get data from the page.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I think you misunderstood my goal. I'm using unittest only to run two functions in parallel because I haven't found a better way to do this. I am not using the test functions to test anything, their main purpose is to return something, in this case a string. The example code I provided is not perfect, I just made it to explain my problem. I couldn't get your example code running but it seems to be that the functions in test1 won't be running parallel. I'm actually aware of your the first "extra note" but I just provided a sloppy sample.

Comment: I'd very much like to try the code you provided but I can't get it to work. get_thing1(self) and get_thing2(self) get errors. With (self) and without (self).

Comment: Try now... I think I fixed it but I don't have a way to test it